# How big of a chance would you have?

Tags: probability

If you have 1000 cups and under 5% of them is a ball. Question is. If you take randomly 20 cups how big of a chance is there that at least under one of them is a ball and how do you calculate it?

Comment: This is a routine probability calculation if you're starting out learning probability. Please edit the question to tell us what you know so far and where you are stuck. Could you solve a smaller problem, say with $4$ cups half of which have a ball and you pick two?

Comment: @Johannes see ethan bolker's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider calculating the probability of getting the opposite of what you want.

- How would you word the opposite case?
- Once you calculate that probability, how is it related to the probability you want?

Spoiler:

> The opposite case is that none of the cups have a ball under them. So we choose $20$ of the $950$ that don't have a ball, and divide by the number of ways to choose $20$ from the $1000$. The probability of what you want is then $1$ minus this probability: $P = 1 - {950 \choose 20}/{1000 \choose 20}$.